# Is it possible to set a cookie to expiry at the end of session and after 1 day?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am using JavaScript cookies like in this guide here - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp and have a cookie set up to expire on session.

Is it possible to also have it expire after 24 hours? So if the session is longer than 24 hours it will expire

Comment: You probably would need to do 2 cookies to pull it off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cookie will either expire on session end, or on a specific date, because in order to make the cookie expire on session end you actually omit the date to make it work.

unless you create 2 cookies one for session end and one on a date
the function below is from the page you posted. use it to calculate the date and set the cookie where `exdays=1`. else just use the last line of the function omitting the `expires` so it can expire on session end

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```